# Use Javascript to update attribute of dynamically created HTML element

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form with a Select and 7 PHP dynamically created InputBoxes. The boxes by default are disabled and my plan is to enable them triggered by a change in the value of the Select.

For this I have built a Javascript function but I get an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null) when I try to change the Select and as a result, the InputBoxes don't get enabled.

Thank you in advance for assisting me in resolving this.

HTML/PHP Code Extract:

```
<table>
<td>
<select name="activity1" id="activity1" disabled onchange="enableInputs()">
   <option value="1">Value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Value 2</option>
   <option value="3">Value 3</option>                   
</select>   
</td>

<?php
    $WeekDays = array("monday1","tuesday1","wednesday1","thursday1", 
                      "friday1", "saturday1", "sunday1");

    for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) 
    {
        echo
            '<td>'.
                '<input value="0" type="text" name="'.$WeekDays[$i].
                        '" id="'.$WeekDays[$i].
                        '" size="5" maxlength="5" disabled ;">'.
            '</td>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function enableInputs()
{
  var rCnt = 1;
  var DaysOfWeek = new 
     Array("monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday", "friday", "saturday", 
     "sunday"); 
  for (x=1;x<=rCnt;x++)
  {
    for (i=0;i<=6;i++)
    {
      document.getElementById(DaysOfWeek[i]+x).removeAttribute("disabled");
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Error message is pretty clear, you are accessing an object which does not exist. Maybe the indices of your DaysOfWeek var are wrong or the element ID does not exist. It's up to you to do some debug (console.log or alert)

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Element ID didn't exist. I've added it in my post, re-tested but still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your PHP code you are giving `name` attribute

```
<input name="'.$WeekDays[$i].'">
```

and you are fetching

```
document.getElementById()
```

which will get you empty string.

Solution:
either change html to:

```
<input id="'.$WeekDays[$i].'">
```

or use `document.getElementsByName(DaysOfWeek)` to fetch the list of nodes.

Comment: You probably meant  "either change html to: <input id="'.$WeekDays[$i].'">" not "name=XYZ"

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've added the missing id attribute in my PHP script but still get the same error. Viewing the source on the page confirms that the element of that id exists. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Then there is possible chance that your `DaysOfWeek[i]+x` is not making valid strings. better share that part of code as well.

Comment: Eventually got it working now. Last piece of the jigsaw was a missing double quote mark! Thanks everyone for your help.